# How to solve uninitialized local variable used?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int x;  int counter;
    while (scanf_s("%d", &x) != 0)
    {
        puts("Enter the a signed number : ");
        if (x % 2 == 0) { counter=counter++; }
    }
    printf(" %d pair numbers", counter);
}
```

I get

> uninitialized local variable counter used.

The program is supposed to keep asking for numbers until it gets zero and tells us the amount of pairs given.

Comment: What's unclear about the warning? Where do you get it? Just read the text and understand it!

Comment: `int x, counter = 0;`

Comment: The solution is very clearly to initialize the local variable (`counter`) before you start incrementing it in the loop. Read your code **and** the error message, which tells you *uninitialized local variable **counter** used*.

Comment: It actually *is* easy here. You can choose between two variables that could be uninitialized. 50% chance...

Comment: You are trying to use `counter` to increment it. What do you think the value of `counter` is when the loop executes for the first time?

Comment: @MichaelGeary: No. The problem is `counter = counter++` (which is also wrong).

Comment: `scanf_s("%d", &x) != 0` is "problematic". What if an error is encountered? Read the documentation of the functions you use!

Comment: Ok I removed counter = counter++ and wrote counter++ and initialized it to 0 but the problem now is even when I Put 0 it keeps asking me for a number !!

Comment: scanf_s does not return the integer that you read in, read the documentation to see what it returns. To exit do something like `(while x != 0)` and call scanf from within the loop

Comment: `scanf_s` is optional by the standard and does not add any safety to your code. Use the normal `scanf` function.

Comment: @G.Khalaf  I think  that the problem is that due to this prompt "Enter the a signed number : " the compiler does not know whether to deal with a number of with the number.:)

Comment: Um..."how to solve uninitialized local variable used"? Well, *initialize* it!

Comment: @G.Khalaf: "problem now is even when I Put 0 it keeps asking me for a number". But what steps did you take to stop it from asking? What part of your code is supposed to terminate the cycle when you enter 0?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem you are facing is cause by your use of the variable `counter` without initializing it. This is exactly what the compiler is telling you.

When you try to execute `counter=counter++;` for the first time, `counter` has no definied value. You might think by `int counter;` it gets initialized with `0`, but this is wrong in C.

The next problem is the line `counter=counter++;` itself. If you want to increment `counter`, just use `counter++`. Depending on the compile you are using, the use of `counter=counter++` should give you at least a warning. On my machine using Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42) I get

> warning: multiple unsequenced modifications to 'counter' [-Wunsequenced]

Then you try to loop until you read `0`. But `scanf()` (use this instead of the Microsoft specific `scanf_s()`) does *not* return what it has read from `stdin` but the number of input items assigned. It returns `0` in the event of a matching failure.

So here is what to do:

1. Initialize `counter`
2. Replace `counter=counter++` with `counter++`
3. Use another loop breaking condition than the return value of `scanf()`

One approach could be the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int x=0;
    int counter=0;

    do{
        printf("Enter the a signed number: ");
        scanf("%d", &x);
        if (!(x % 2)){
            counter++;
        }
    } while(x);

    printf(" %d pair numbers\n", counter);
}
```

Comment: Although you advised what `scanf` does not return, the answer fails to consider what it *does* return. Moreover it treats the end cue `0` as data before quitting.

Comment: thanks a lot but what do I do to pause the screen after hitting 0 ?

Comment: @WeatherVane: citing the BSD Library Manual `scanf` "[..]return the number of input items assigned" as written in the answer. But you are right, no details are provided.

Comment: "Depending on the compile you are using…" - It is undefined behaviour, nothing else! The compiler is free to do anything it wants, including code to format your harddrive. No need for a diagnostic message, though. And while MS indeed have their own set of `_s` functions, `scanf_s` could as well be the standard function. For `%d` it just does not make any difference.

Comment: @Olaf: I just mentioned that some compiler might give warnings, others might not.

Comment: @datell: You missed the point! The problem is not the warning!

Comment: At least OP's code check the return value of the input with `while (scanf_s("%d", &x) != 0)`  (which should have been `while (scanf_s("%d", &x) == 1)`.  This answer does not check the return value of `scanf("%d", &x);` and then uses `x` in `if (!(x % 2)){` leading to a potential use of the variable `x` without a certain value.  Best to check the return value of input functions.  "Use another loop breaking condition than the return value of scanf()" is not good advice.  OP should use the return value _and_ something like `x` compared to 0.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize counter to 0 before trying to increment it. Also `counter = counter++;` is redundant (and undefined!). Just use `counter++`

Comment: The problem with `counter = counter++;` is not that it is redundant, but that it causes undefined behavior.

Comment: @DavidBowling true, but if it did behave as OP expected it would still be redundant

Comment: @Mitchel0022: And if C was Java, it was well defined. That is pointless. It **is** UB and done!

Comment: @DavidBowling fair point

Comment: @Mitchel0022-- as is often the case in such questions, there is more than one UB here; the UB to which I referred in my comment has to do with sequence points. [See this famous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-undefined-behavior)